# Assigning IF statement outcome to a variable - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to assign the outcome of an IF statement to a variable in JS?

```
  if (busNumber[currentBus][2] == route[0]){
     console.log("Correct!");
  }
  else {
     console.log("Incorrect!");
  }
```

Is it possible to assign Correct or Incorrect to a variable so i can thereafter call it in other areas of the program?

Answer (score 1):

```
var result;
if (busNumber[currentBus][2] == route[0]){
    result = "Correct!";
}
else {
    result = "Incorrect!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible by defining the variable upfront and then assign the value to it:

```
var output;
if (busNumber[currentBus][2] == route[0]){
    console.log("Correct!");
    output = "Correct!";
} else {
    console.log("Incorrect!");
    output = "Incorrect!";
}
console.log('Output: ' + output);
```

You now can use the variable *output* in the rest of your script.

Comment: Tried this earlier - i keep receiving reverse or an undefined outcome when i call output elsewhere.

Comment: This works see the following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oje21wup/ change the match variable to get a different output.

Answer (score 0):

You can in a way

```
var result = function() {
    if (busNumber[currentBus][2] == route[0]) {
       return "Correct!";
    }
    else {
       return "Incorrect!";
    } 
}();
```

though, technically you're assigning the result of a function to a variable